# Average a null columns in stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I want to average null columns.

This is my stored procedure :

```
SELECT 
    AVG(planned) AS Planned,
    AVG(achieved) AS Achieved 
FROM 
    Port 
INNER JOIN 
    Technology ON Port.portID = Technology.portRef
```

I bind this stored procedure to a chart using datasource and when the column is null the C# code throws this error:

> Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.

How can I handle my stored procedure to `avg` those null columns?

Comment: what do you expect AVG(null) to return?

Comment: What do you mean by average null columns, what do you think would be average of null ?

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the query does not return any values. Use this

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(avg(planned),0) as Planned,
    coalesce(avg(achieved),0) as Achieved 
FROM 
    Port inner join Technology on Port.portID = Technology.portRef
```

Comment: I don't know if that's right, shouldn't it be avg(coalesce(planned,0))?  At the moment, it's averaging the column and then seeing if it's NULL.  Shouldn't it be seeing if the value is NULL, and then averaging it by interpreting NULL values as 0?

Comment: @phillyd - You need to ask the OP that question.  ***Really*** you shouldn't do *anything*; `NULL` is an unknown or missing value, it quite certainly isn't `0`, so the average function is doing it right.  But the OP can't handle that in their C# code, so the OP needs to specify which fudge to use.  Not because the average function is wrong, and either use of COALESCE is right, but because the OP is asking for a fudge, but not specifying how they want the result to be fudged.

Comment: @Dems Absolutely - my next question was going to be: Is interpreting a NULL as 0 what you want? It will be used to calculate the average, skewing the figures with values that are supposed to be missing.  I see what you mean about AVG though, I suppose that is considering NULL values as missing values.

Comment: All, if there are no data in the table or query does not return any rows, all aggregates return NULL. See this example

declare @t table(col int)
select avg(col),sum(col) from @t

Answer (score 2):

another way

```
SELECT avg(isnull(planned,0))as Planned,avg(isnull(achieved,0))  as Achieved 
FROM Port inner join Technology on Port.portID = Technology.portRef
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `unpivot`

```
select id, AVG(Q)
from (select * from myTable) a
unpivot(Q for QQ IN(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)) b
group by id
```

If all the columns are `null`, it won't return anything though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several people getting confused whether to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`.
I would strongly recommend `COALESCE`. In some cases both will run fine, but in some cases `ISNULL` if not properly handled will give wrong output.

Please check the below snippet :

```
SELECT  
    ISNULL(Nullif('test', 'test'), '12345') AS using_isnull,
    COALESCE(Nullif('test', 'test'), '12345') AS using_coalesce,
    ISNULL(Nullif('test', 'test'), 12345) AS int_using_isnull,
    COALESCE(Nullif('test', 'test'), 12345) AS int_using_coalesce
```